# Electric shock and ground potential question

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, resistance, grounding

1. Why don't I get shocked when I touch my phone charger cable connector while the switch is still on?
2. What happens if ground potential is not 0V (e.g. 150V or lower or higher?) Will the energy still arrive to it or will I or V or R be affected?

Comment: What switch is still on? Are you referring to some switch on mains socket that might exist in some countries?

Comment: Where in the connector did you touch? Why do you expect to get shocked? What is the expected voltage on the connector and terminals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the SE community help you properly, you should first put in some [research effort for you subject of interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

[image]

1. In order for you to get shocked when you touch the connector there must be a difference in potential between the part with which you touch the connector and the part of your body with which you touch the ground. So, if you stand on your feet and if you touch the connector with your hand usually there should be no difference of potential. However, if there is a difference of potential, let's say 5V, you won't feel much, as the body resistance will limit the current flowing through your body. However, if the difference of potential is 220V [AC or DC] then your body won't be able to deal with the avalanche of free electrons flowing through your body without significant damage to your body. [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/) explains the medical effects, current has over human body. Also, keep in mind that the characteristic resistance of the human body depends on factors like skin temperature, skin density, skin wetness, body height, body fat, body age. More in the link above.

   [image]
2. By now it should be clear...

EDIT:
Ever wondered why birds don't get KFC'ed when yelling at people from high voltage power lines?

Comment: im sorry i confused you. for no.2, i meant if the ground like soil ground  is 150v or something and the ground wire is 220v or something, what happens? potential difference u mean bare voltage or the voltage between 2 points like 220v  minus 150v?

Comment: @Alienxalienz, to keep it simple, voltage is the potential difference between any 2 given points. It really doesn't matter what or where are those 2 points, can be 2 points on a wood board (see electric woodworking on our favorite (ads) streaming platform), 2 points between sky and earth (which range at about 10kV if I remember correctly), and so on. The  thing to remember is that current depends on the potential difference and the characteristic resistance between those 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 2-prong ungrounded plug on the charger:

1. The phone charger DC side is isolated from the AC side by a transformer inside the charger itself. There is no direct path between the line input and the output. That is, the output is ‘floating’ with respect to both the line voltage and the ground and neutral. Therefore, no (or little) current passes between the output and ground if a connection is made by you touching it.
2. Nothing happens. The DC output is still isolated. No (or little) current flows to ground.

About the 'little' part. This kind of power supply has a name: Safety Extra Low Voltage, or SELV. SELV power supplies are isolated and have outputs less than 60V. This makes them ‘touch safe’, that is, unlikely to deliver a harmful shock if the user comes in contact with the output voltage.

The line-to-output isolation isn't perfect: some line current couples across the transformer and also via the *Y caps* that bypass interference noise back to the line. This is called *leakage current*. The amount of leakage current allowed for SELV supplies is about 3mA; less than that for medical-grade units.

You can see this leakage as a voltage measured between ground and the charger's output. It can be as high as about 60VAC with nothing grounding the output. It will decrease to just a few volts when you touch it.